# Como recibir una API en Vue desde Laravel en desarrollo

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

buenas tardes. Tengo una duda para recibir una API en Vue que tengo desde Laravel. Como lo harìa? xD. Ya tengo en Axios hecho para recibir los datos

**EstudianteView.vue**

```
onBeforeMount( async () => {
    await axios.get('127.0.0.1:8000/api/estudiantes')
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

Y en API.php en el programa de Laravel

```
Route::resource('/estudiantes', EstudianteController::class);
```

Que me crea la ruta donde se van a entregar estudiantes. Y en ese controlador tengo la función que devuelve los datos de los estudiantes.

EstudianteController.php

```
 public function index() : JsonResource
{
    return EstudianteResource::collection(Estudiante::all());
}
```

Aquí llega mi duda como recibo la API en un proyecto de Vue, que viene desde un proyecto en Laravel. **No estoy en produccion, estoy en desarrollo.** Al ejecutarlo sale esto en la consola.

```
GET http://localhost:8080/127.0.0.1:8000/api/estudiantes 404 (Not Found)
```

Entiendo que es por los puertos, ya que el programa de Laravel corre en un puerto y el de Vue en otro, entonces capaz, que al pedirlo se sobrepone. La verdad me quede trancado con eso, si alguien sabe como se puede recibir los valores, se lo agredecería mucho

Comment: Que pasa si sacas `127.0.0.1:8000` de `127.0.0.1:8000/api/estudiantes`? En que puerto esta escuchando laravel y en que puerto vue?

Comment: Laravel esta en el 8000 y vue en el 8080. Si se lo saco igual no da, aparece el mismo error sin esa parte

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ No se si debería ponerlos en el mismo puerto o como colocar en axios para que busque en otro puerto

Comment: Ya encontre el problema me falto el http:// igual gracias por todo.